# initialize component when rerouting back to it

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Before getting into code, I have a conceptual question:
I'm routing from component A (Main list of items) to component B (form to create new item), and then from component B back to component A.
I would like to update the component A with the new item. One option is by subscribing to a subject in a service which injected to these 2 components.
I would like to know if there is a another option. I'm aware the routing saves state of the component and the ngOnInit event is not invoked when routing back to component A, so I can't use this event for subscribing to the service. Is there another life cycle event I can use when re-routing to the component ?

Comment: ngOnInit should invoke when you navigate back to comp A. Are you injecting a new service instance again to comp B instead of using same service instance?

Answer (score 0):

Don't be aware when you route back to the Component A the `ngOnInit` will be fired and you can fetch the data from your API to update the UI

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `RouteGuard` to pre-load the data for the component with a `canActivate` function. It will block the route to continue until the data needed has been loaded, then allow it to continue and render the view.

In your routing configuration you would do something like

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  //...
  {
    path: 'example',
    component: ExampleComponent,
    canActivate: [PreloadDataGuard] //<-- 
  }
  //...
];
```

The guard will handle loading of the data and should return an `Observable<boolean>` or a `Promise<boolean>` when done.

This is even easier if you use a store pattern for your data, such as NGRX or NGXS or Redux. In that case, have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/razroo/how-to-pre-load-data-in-angular-route-guards-739e58093956), even though I think it can help you further along even if you're not using a store.